# Dart parameter default value syntax: colon or equal

Tags: dart

What is the difference between these two syntaxes for setting a default value for a parameter in Dart:

```
class Test {
  Test({
    int x: 2,
    int y = 3,
  });
}
```

I tried both of them and they seem to be completely identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same. At least for now. The [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-positional-parameters) says:

> Deprecation note: Old code might use a colon (:) instead of = to set
> default values of named parameters. The reason is that originally,
> only : was supported for named parameters. That support might be
> deprecated, so we recommend that you use = to specify default values.

So avoid using the colon in the future as it may be removed at some point.